# Azure Devops Server self hosted docker agent setup SSL errors

Tags: docker, ssl, azure-devops

I'm trying to set up a proof of concept Azure Devops Server environment including a self hosted Docker agent on Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS, following the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/docker?view=azure-devops).
When I attempt to start the container with this command it fails with an SSL error from curl:

```
myuser@ubuntu20-04dockertest:~$ sudo docker run -e AZP_URL=https://win-k58ocndvak6/DefaultCollection -e AZP_TOKEN=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX -e AZP_AGENT_NAME=scs-docker-agent dockeragent:latest
[sudo] password for myuser: 
1. Determining matching Azure Pipelines agent...
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

I have tried with a self signed certificate in the Azure Devops Server IIS bindings and by installing Active Directory Certificate Services and configuring the Azure Devops Server as a standalone root CA, issuing a certificate and applying it Azure Devops Server IIS bindings. Both the self signed certificate and the CA certificate were imported into the Ubuntu machines trusted certificate store. Neither of these configurations work but running curl against the Azure Devops Server URL seems fine:

```
myuser@ubuntu20-04dockertest:~$ curl -v https://win-k58ocndvak6/DefaultCollection
*   Trying 192.168.122.204:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to win-k58ocndvak6 (192.168.122.204) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=AU; ST=WA; L=Perth; O=WIN-K58OCNDVAK6; OU=SCS-DEV; CN=WIN-K58OCNDVAK6
*  start date: Sep 24 08:06:11 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Sep 24 08:16:11 2021 GMT
*  common name: WIN-K58OCNDVAK6 (matched)
*  issuer: CN=WIN-K58OCNDVAK6-CA-1
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x55d60c17ddb0)
> GET /DefaultCollection HTTP/2
> Host: win-k58ocndvak6
> user-agent: curl/7.68.0
> accept: */*
```

Does anyone know what's going on here?

A way to get the "docker run" command to not care about SSL would also be fine, this is just a proof of concept Dev setup.

Thanks :)

Comment: How about running command `sudo update-ca-certificates` before `docker run`?